# Android: Building with ant doen't reflect change without ant clean

Tags: android, ant

For the past few months, i have been developing for android devices .. and i am using vim as primary means of development. I just feel comfortable and faster in vim than eclipse .. and since i am using vim .. i use command line tools to build and run the app .

each time i do `ant clean && ant debug && ant installd`

but using ant clean each time makes the process long .. atleast a minute to build and 30 sec to install ..

i have tried to skip ant clean some times `ant debug && ant installd` but the problem here is my new changes doesn't get reflected without `ant clean` ..

But my colleagues who use eclipse to program in android are usually faster in this build and run process .. can any one explain me how to increase performance of command line tools ..